# XML parsing using PHP

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I have a .out file which has xml content like this.

```
<header stub>
    <article type="audio">
        <addedDate>2010-03-11 05:11:57</addedDate>
        <thumbnail>http://fgsdfff/4588/thumbnail_9.jpg</thumbnail>
        <asset="blarga.mp3" addedDate="2009-01-07 01:48:37">
            <size>3289048</size>
            <duration>206000</duration>
            <mime_type>audio/mpeg</mime_type>
        </asset>
    </article>
</footer stub>
```

1. I have to add `<?xml version="1.0"?>` and `</xml>` at the start of the xml and at the end respectively.
2. I have to replace `<header stub>` and `</footer stub>` with `<channel>` and `</channel>`  tags respectively.
3. You might have noticed the XML is not well formed in the `<asset>` tag. It has to be like `<asset url="blarga.mp3" addedDate="2009-01-07 01:48:37">`. How do I add the url attribute?
4. In the thumbnail tag, i have to remove _9 from the jpg's name.

And finally, i have to convert the .out to .xml file.

Please help me with these

Comment: That isn't XML content... at least, the sample you've given isn't

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: ah better, helps if code is formatted.

Comment: I strongly suggest to fix the .out file generator instead of hacking around the invalid XML in the results.

Comment: Not sure you'd want to have the closing </xml> tag at the end. There is no opening <xml> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$content = file_get_content OR mysql_query;//"YOUR XML CONTENT FROM FILE OR MYSQL";
$content = "<?xml version="1.0"?>" . $content . "</xml>";
$content = str_replace("<header stub>", "<channel>", $content);
$content = str_replace("</footer stub>", "</channel>", $content);
$content = str_replace("<asset=", "<asset url=", $content);
$content = str_replace("thumbnail_9.jpg", "thumbnail.jpg", $content);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class.

An example of its usage can be found [here](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?t=14165)

Comment: I doubt that SimpleXML will be useful here because the content is not well-formed XML.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out as the question changed. Have modified my answer too.